# Sphinx Snippet function makes mistakes?

Tags: sphinx

While querying the best results in my resultset, I'm also generating a snippet with Sphinx. To do so, I use the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT id, SNIPPET(Content, '(55byddQ%)') AS Snippet FROM RTTest WHERE MATCH(' (55byddQ%)');
```

However, this query returns me some wrong results (id 1 for instance):

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | snippet                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 |  ... 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% _oE% <b>55byddQ%</b> udCuJ5W7Ew%% 64z3fsHm ;Jbjc80%  ... 0yMqTJfByLxZRwNu9zYXv0m1miVLwus_fxl0<b>ZxNkrfpN</b>GNsG8KeEzr1fn05yTa7fJkq9ZHSjHLB2 ...  55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% 6oHiYsPl<b>Qg%% _oE</b>% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ov ...  |
|    4 |  ... 7IH0ddLsScfhx74tjS6HNgj5z6j2XnY9xWQgdCw% 65bzdM;3QNbp36k2 sd2vdcrxQd;j ;ov5YsDiR8D33ak2jjaJ <b>55byddQ%</b> ;ovkIZezHYC1 u8qgIJCvHYS1n;121GHWbg%% uA%%  ... 7ZHk sd2veNPqV9njwQ%% 5p36f8g% 44jzZdToS8TxzKQ2iD2I <b>55byddQ%</b> udanIJS2FA%% v9a6JpayFo23n;xy0w%% uA%%  ...                          |
|    9 |  ...  utSnJ5awFo0% 4YA% udelKJO3HIe7 uNSjIJazFoK1lvpw1G7bbQ%% <b>55byddQ%</b> vQ%% upP4fsu7V9Dq2LpziTXfPk2Znw%% ;oj5ddToSNHmyqIoiDeK _8r4fA%%  ...  utSnJZexFoU% 4YA% vdCjJpazE4W1m;p9 uNSkIJazFYWwnP5y12vcbA%% <b>55byddQ%</b> u9emJJa3F4CxmQ%% 7YXlZNbiTw%% utS7IZSuFoSzmg%% utSsI5c%  ...              |
|   23 |  ... 7ov6dMPxVw%% 7pb5fQ%% 4Yrydd7iUN3twQ%% 4Yo% <b>55byddQ%</b> ;Is% 7Zz1fNPnQQ%% 7ov6dMPxVw%% 7pb5fQ%% ... 5oX7ddU% 7pb5fQ%% 4Yrydd7iUN3twQ%% 4Yo% <b>55byddQ%</b> ;Is% 7Zz1fNPnQQ%% 7o36dQ%%  ... 7ZzidcjwTdvs3A%% 7pb5fQ%% 4Yrydd7iUN3twQ%% 4Yo% <b>55byddQ%</b> ;Is% 7Zz1fNPnQQ%% 7o36dQ%%  ...      |
|   29 |  ...  ;Izz 6YLwecrqRcDn3A%% 54I% 7o36ddQ% 4Yo% <b>55byddQ%</b> ;Is% 54LwddQ% 8Yvj ;Izz _4HkZs;gQcc% ...                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
|   34 |  ...  7ovkc8Pw _4HgddTiSA%% 6ZHieMnxTcfnyw%% 4IX4dNXrRd;n3A%% 4Yo% <b>55byddQ%</b> ;Is% 6ZHieMPtUN3hzrgh ;Izz 64v4fsPgUN3twQ%% _4s% ...                                                                                                                                                                   |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see in the snippet of id 1, it is also highlighting hits like: `0yMqTJfByLxZRwNu9zYXv0m1miVLwus_fxl0<b>ZxNkrfpN</b>GNsG8KeEzr1fn05yTa7fJkq9ZHSjHLB2`, while I'm searching for: `55byddQ%`.

Therefore, the snippet function is not returning me correct results, but I can't figure out why not.

***Config:***
My words / sentences are stored encrypted and always consist of `a-Z`, `0-9`, `_`, `;` or `%` as you can see in my configuration `charset_table` directive.

The configuration:

```
index RTTest
{
  type            = rt
  path            = /mnt/data001/RTTest
  rt_field        = Name
  rt_field        = Extension
  rt_field        = Content
  rt_field        = Tags
  rt_attr_uint    = Reference
  rt_attr_uint    = FileSize
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModified
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedYear
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedMonth
  rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedDay
  rt_attr_string  = Content
  rt_mem_limit    = 1024M
  charset_table   = A..Z, a..z, 0..9, _, ;, %
  ondisk_attrs    = pool
}

searchd
{
  listen                = 9306:mysql41
  log                   = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
  read_timeout          = 5
  max_children          = 30
  pid_file              = /var/run/searchd.pid
  max_packet_size       = 128M
  binlog_path           = /mnt/data001
}
```

***EDIT:***
The original document string which was inserted is:

```
7ZE% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% _oE% 55byddQ% udCuJ5W7Ew%% 64z3fsHm ;Jbjc80% 5os% 4I0% ;Iv7cdX5 64z3fsHmQA%% 5YXydQ%% ;Iz3fs3w 7ovk ;Izz 4Yrwfw%% _oHxcdTnVw%% 643yKs;uRdPnn;x1ySiAP2lNHDKc7MFiHbefyEENCs_YOA%% 6YrieMntXQ%% ;oX4eMPgT9E% ;MLyYw%% _Ij3fsjqStM% ;IH3fQ%% 6oXuZMPx 7I3lZNTqRsH2xqMq 64H4ZMPx 7ZHkf9bm _4U% ;A%% u9a4Jp6tFoOwgf9y0w%% ;I3z 5I34dQ%% v9KmIpW1EA%% 6YrieMntXev0zqIsgjuFPWp0K4YDjNJrOxvP 6YrieMntXev0zqIsgjuFPWp0K4YDjNJrOxvP 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7ovk 7ZLzYt8% 5Iv3dA%% 7Zy7fMPwV93syr8% _IjzcdXm 7Iv4N9I% 7ovkd8P3 ;Is% 6Yf1ddb3 ;Izz ;Jb3ftXzS8b2 6Yry ;Is% 6ov5ew%% 6Q%% _4j5ZA%% 4Yo% ;Jb3ftXzS8bnwKI% 5os% _4j5ZA%% 5os% 5Iv3dM;tQw%% 55Y% 5IXidQ%% 5Iv3dM;tQw%% 7pb5fQ%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4H4ZA%% 5YXkdM8% udA% 7ic;ZtTqQcY% utSnJw%% uNysI5I% ;Is% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% 64c% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m _5H0esPgUA%% 55byddQ% udCuJ5W7Ew%% 64z3fsHm ;Jbjc80% 5os% 7IH3Yg%% 54jxcQ%% 7IH3Yg%% 7pb3fmUkS93x 64vjfMI% 8Yvj _IjzcdXm 7Is% 5YE% 6Q%% 7oXgf9Q% 6Yry 64z3fsHm ;Izz _Ij3ZMM% 5os% 7ovk 5Iv3dM;tQw%% ;Izz 6cr7 55byddQ% ;Ivycd8% 6ZA% udasIJY% 4Jbl ;Is% 54A% _5A% u92m 54A% 75c% u9Km 7Jb;ZsPx _4Hkd8Pp 6pH1eMLiSsfpyg%% ;Iz3fs0% 8Yvj ;oHkaQ%% 5ZH1eA%% 7ovk 4IH6YA%% 5Y3i 7pbzZcjnSN3hx6kq 75ZVrGUcQdo% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;IH6PonmXMA% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuyEA%% 7oXu vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYu2Fg%% 7cn7cc;v ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% 7oLwTZrrUMDy3PZryC2cNCk1Jv_9g5TtnIVy4dBZubnQGYbA0sjQ8XVB9uiM6xB10RIczN2fKjL7hIRlM0ccl1m4i6mGSi2cuaSJ5qCEH267wTLL2kMqoJ6DoE_dPGlLS8q2ybFqDIF97RPvktwXKg;p4fmYHMz8Xr;sPAEXMZF6F;O91WtjLFbJH1xlRsltKkgCxfQhVuF7aOzfd5Xt_wQA9mz4up6pJgZGEspHPCZ00vjfzbvHE7Aohrl1BD;OxElQvQDaoca5lij4ov9cEyRbdyhPHqU7Ey_7B79eB5DFz1JbuIcvw6xhEh_hOOssAWxzJ6s_ohjkhCRiSSnPCj8NyqTVrfuAHsOaSawe _4f_fcPgTNHu ;Jb3ftXzS8b2 74n0eA%% _icgd8Pt udQ% 7IG7IpW7EIc% 6oXy 54jyddXvS9E% 8oH4ZNTiSNE% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuz 4YriddTtQcA% 4JDiYNW5C5v33aAggj6LNk66Yt1fbunAAncDASQwInW1ftBPE300AxE4sFft_8ecpSPCb4J07XA6BqpabTknmAZ635iAoEj;tTYTH;In2tF7x;TAOiVYfx6UOdVMFCt6zu0M1zNT0A2crIS0yMqTJfByLxZRwNu9zYXv0m1miVLwus_fxl0ZxNkrfpNGNsG8KeEzr1fn05yTa7fJkq9ZHSjHLB2sYJ2myBVjHGLq8FgAHMNza6hqdnUrp4p8SZZ0zPrSz0e327dLboLpZzhU8So7kuNUzR15tOLMUQ14j5lU5qVYlsC_BNt1ebEDnc7uRVMn1at1q5mihQgVNkLenOKRZgNyDjr8 ;ov4 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 74HldcjnQcA% 7I3zftX3RdM% u9U% 4oX4Zcfx utSnJw%% uNysJJY% 6Yo% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% 64c% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m 6oHiYsPlQg%% _oE% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 4IH6fMk% 7Iv4dQ%% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% 7pb3fmUkS93x 7IHxccjn ;MLyYw%% _oHmfMPtTcfqwqkqkw%% _5HmddTqSsDnwaghiSw% 6oXuZMPx 7I3lZNTqRsH2xqMq 64H4ZMPx 7ZHkf9bm _Iz5fsM% u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utw% vtY% 7oXu u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utM% vNM% 7cn7cc;v 7pb3fsXsTcfdy6kjhjaKGJ45E69TDWp8jVI% 7pb3fsXsTcfdy6kjhjaKGJ45E69TDWp8jVI% 74H4ddTiSA%% 7cn7cc;v 6YDkddXw 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1Ggz3iLmXwHY1DpncIYAU85 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1Ggz3iLmXwHY1DpncIYAU85 55a5ccjn 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7pb5fQ%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4H4ZA%% 5YXkdM8% u9U% 4oX4Zs;mVg%% utSnJw%% uNysI5A% ;Is% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m 64c% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% _5H0esPgUA%% 6ZM% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 7IH3Yg%% 7pb3fmUkS93x 64vjfMI% 8Yvj _IjzcdXm 7Is% 5YE% 6Q%% 7oXgf9Q% 6Yry 64z3fsHm ;Izz _Ij3ZMM% 5os% 7ovk 5Iv3dM;tQw%% ;Ivycd8% ;Is% 54A% _5A% vNem 54A% 75c% utau 7Jb;ZsPx 5o31f8rm 7oX6ag%% ;Iz3fs3w 4Yo% 6YDgccjgQQ%% 5Y3i 7pbzZcjnSN3hx6kq 75ZVrGUcQdo% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;IH6PonmXMA% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuyEA%% 7oXu vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYu2Fg%% 7cn7cc;v ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% 7oLwTZrrUMDy3PZryC2cNCk1Jv_9g5TtnIVy4dBZubnQGYbA0sjQ8XVB9uiM6xB10RIczN2fKjL7hIRlM0ccl1m4i6mGSi2cuaSJ5qCEH267wTLL2kMqoJ6DoE_dPGlLS8q2ybFqDIF97RPvktwXKg;p4fmYHMz8Xr;sPAEXMZF6F;O91WtjLFbJH1xlRsltKkgCxfQhVuF7aOzfd5Xt_wQA9mz4up6pJgZGEspHPCZ00vjfzbvHE7Aohrl1BD;OxElQvQDaoca5lij4ov9cEyRbdyhPHqU7Ey_7B79eB5DFz1JbuIcvw6xhEh_hOOssAWxzJ6s_ohjkhCRiSSnPCj8NyqTVrfuAHsOaSawe _4f_fcPgTNHu ;Jb3ftXzS8b2 74n0eA%% _icgd8Pt udQ% 7IG7IpW7EIc% 6oXy 54jyddXvS9E% 8oH4ZNTiSNE% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuz 4YriddTtQcA% 4JDiYNW5C5v33aAggj6LNk66Yt1fbunAAncDASQwInW1ftBPE300AxE4sFft_8ecpSPCb4J07XA6BqpabTknmAZ635iAoEj;tTYTH;In2tF7x;TAOiVYfx6UOdVMFCt6zu0M1zNT0A2crIS0yMqTJfByLxZRwNu9zYXv0m1miVLwus_fxl0ZxNkrfpNGNsG8KeEzr1fn05yTa7fJkq9ZHSjHLB2sYJ2myBVjHGLq8FgAHMNza6hqdnUrp4p8SZZ0zPrSz0e327dLboLpZzhU8So7kuNUzR15tOLMUQ14j5lU5qVYlsC_BNt1ebEDnc7uRVMn1at1q5mihQgVNkLenOKRZgNyDjr8 ;ov4 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 74HldcjnQcA% 5Yv4ZMfk u9Q% 4oX4Zcfx utSnJw%% udKsI5Y% 6Yo% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m 64c% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% 6oHiYsPlQg%% _oE% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 548% 7Iv4dQ%% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% 7pb3fmUkS93x 7IHxccjn ;MLyYw%% _oHmfMPtTcfqwqkqkw%% _5HmddTqSsDnwaghiSw% 6oXuZMPx 7I3lZNTqRsH2xqMq 64H4ZMPx 7ZHkf9bm _Iz5fsM% u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utw% vtY% 7oXu u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utM% vNM% 7cn7cc;v 7pb3fsXsTcfdy6kjhjaKGJ45E69TDWp8jVI% 7pb3fsXsTcfdy6kjhjaKGJ45E69TDWp8jVI% 74H4ddTiSA%% 7cn7cc;v 6YDkddXw 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1Ggz3iLmXwHY1DpncIYAU85 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1Ggz3iLmXwHY1DpncIYAU85 55a5ccjn 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7pb5fQ%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4H4ZA%% 5JH4dM8% u9Q% 4oX4Zs;mVg%% utSnJw%% udKsIJM% ;Is% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m 64c% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% _5H0esPgUA%% 6ZM% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 4IH6fMk% 7pb3fmUkS93x 4Q%% 64X4N9I% 7o34dA%% ;Izz 6ov5e8Pn ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 64vjfMI% 8Yvj _IjzcdXm 6YDy ;Izz ;Jbjc80% 7IHicc;vVw%% 7ovk 5YE% ;Jbjc80% 54A% _5A% vdWh 54A% 75c% vNGh 7Jb;ZsPx 4IH;e8k% 6icyeNQ% 5YX4aQ%% ;Iz3fs3w 4Yo% 6YDgccjgQQ%% 5Y3i 7pbzZcjnSN3hx6kq 75ZVrGUcQdo% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;IH6PonmXMA% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuyEA%% 7oXu vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYu2Fg%% 7cn7cc;v ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% 7oLwTZrrUMDy3PZryC2cNCk1Jv_9g5TtnIVy4dBZubnQGYbA0sjQ8XVB9uiM6xB10RIczN2fKjL7hIRlM0ccl1m4i6mGSi2cuaSJ5qCEH267wTLL2kMqoJ6DoE_dPGlLS8q2ybFqDIF97RPvktwXKg;p4fmYHMz8Xr;sPAEXMZF6F;O91WtjLFbJH1xlRsltKkgCxfQhVuF7aOzfd5Xt_wQA9mz4up6pJgZGEspHPCZ00vjfzbvHE7Aohrl1BD;OxElQvQDaoca5lij4ov9cEyRbdyhPHqU7Ey_7B79eB5DFz1JbuIcvw6xhEh_hOOssAWxzJ6s_ohjkhCRiSSnPCj8NyqTVrfuAHsOaSawe _4f_fcPgTNHu ;Jb3ftXzS8b2 74n0eA%% _icgd8Pt udQ% 7IG7IpW7EIc% 6oXy 54jyddXvS9E% 8oH4ZNTiSNE% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuz 4YriddTtQcA% 4JDiYNW5C5v33aAggj6LNk66Yt1fbunAAncDASQwInW1ftBPE300AxE4sFft_8ecpSPCb4J07XA6BqpabTknmAZ635iAoEj;tTYTH;In2tF7x;TAOiVYfx6UOdVMFCt6zu0M1zNT0A2crIS0yMqTJfByLxZRwNu9zYXv0m1miVLwus_fxl0ZxNkrfpNGNsG8KeEzr1fn05yTa7fJkq9ZHSjHLB2sYJ2myBVjHGLq8FgAHMNza6hqdnUrp4p8SZZ0zPrSz0e327dLboLpZzhU8So7kuNUzR15tOLMUQ14j5lU5qVYlsC_BNt1ebEDnc7uRVMn1at1q5mihQgVNkLenOKRZgNyDjr8 ;ov4 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 74HldcjnQcA% 5Yv4ZMfk u9Q% 4oX4Zcfx utSnJw%% udGsJZ4% 6Yo% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% 64c% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% 6oHiYsPlQg%% _oE% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 4IH6fMk% 4Q%% 64X4 _4Hz ;Iz;Yw%% _4z;YMvmSsA% 4Zc% 6ov5e8Pn 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 64v6fMPgUN3twQ%% 6ZA% udD_IJY% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% 7pb3fmUkS93x 7IHxccjn ;MLyYw%% _oHmfMPtTcfqwqkqkw%% _5HmddTqSsDnwaghiSw% 6oXuZMPx 7I3lZNTqRsH2xqMq 64H4ZMPx 7ZHkf9bm _Iz5fsM% u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utw% vtY% 7oXu u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utM% vNM% 7cn7cc;v 7pb3fsXsTcfdy6kjhjaKGJ45E69TDWp8jVI% 7pb3fsXsTcfdy6kjhjaKGJ45E69TDWp8jVI% 74H4ddTiSA%% 7cn7cc;v 6YDkddXw 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1Ggz3iLmXwHY1DpncIYAU85 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1Ggz3iLmXwHY1DpncIYAU85 55a5ccjn 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7pb5fQ%% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m 6oXuZMPxCsDv3Iw0gjadM8D13CTG _4H4ZA%% 5JH4dM8% u9Q% 4oX4Zs;mVg%% utSnJw%% udGsIZ8% ;Is% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m _5H0esPgUA%% _oE% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 4IH6fMk% 6YrieMntXQ%% 64X4 8Yvj 4IH6YA%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;43ieA%% 6oH6f9E% _oHxcdTnVw%% 5YHi ;pb;dcjnQdjrxach 75b5ddLmSg%% 54jxcQ%% 4IvzfsLmVsLjwashlSs% _IH4Y83m 5IvxedX3Tdfx 65HlZMnuQcY% _4HkZs;gQQ%% 6Zflf8XqRcDn ;A%% u9U% uM2nJpM% vdOg utSk 7pb5fQ%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4H4ZA%% 5Yv4dMf6 4oX4ZcfxXQ%% u9Q% utSnJw%% u96nKA%% _Ik% ;Is% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m _5H0esPgUA%% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 7IH3Yg%% 6YrieMntXQ%% 7IH3Yg%% 54jxcQ%% 54o% 7pb;dMf6 4Q%% 64v4ds;xSQ%% ;Izz 7Yr1fMnwQdA% 55byddQ% 6p0% ;Jb3ftXzS8bnwKI% 5ovh 4Q%% ;4vjfMI% 5I39dQ%% ;Is% 6ov5ew%% 6Q%% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6pHi ;Iz;Yw%% 55byddQ% 4Zc% 5ovi ;o3lecTvQQ%% 4Yo% 55Tzfg%% 6ov5e8;tQ8c% ;Jb3ftXzS8bnwKI% _4Hz 6oH6f9E% _I31ZNPxQQ%% 643yKs;uRdPnn;xxyTKeP8MnjIp8HAMoV;b3ox5O_7CG4A%% 64X4 8Yvj 4IH6YA%% 5YE% _IjzcdXm 5Y3i 7pbzZcjnSN3hx6kq 75ZVrGUcQdo% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;IH6PonmXMA% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuyEA%% 7oXu vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYu2Fg%% 7cn7cc;v ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% 7oLwTZrrUMDy3PZryC2cNCk1Jv_9g5TtnIVy4dBZubnQGYbA0sjQ8XVB9uiM6xB10RIczN2fKjL7hIRlM0ccl1m4i6mGSi2cuaSJ5qCEH26;wTLL2kMqoJ6DoE_dPGlLWk6XQk9YEzEulo_yYqZDNl7Km1p2fgCMSMOnV7wrVi;5JRwr1kgGvj72VEAoeCXq5hMkPxWoLJpcYw7V0C1hwNKvpMh0qiEeGMzc;ZNQxbmXpam;J0Nx2cBN4lgzJqH3yBSuWb7WEfPTVJur0mpyqBLtG_aXwIdbISY9;YHTAEqcbpzKSG68A3z5GsJmlWc8Vpu6Y4CjNbLH8S;B7DY5vc12ef9ul_sJpY09aXbm _4f_fcPgTNHu ;Jb3ftXzS8b2 74n0eA%% _icgd8Pt udQ% 7IG7IpW7EIc% 6oXy 54jyddXvS9E% 8oH4ZNTiSNE% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuz 4YriddTtQcA% 4JDiYNW5C5v33aAggj6LNk66Yt1fbunAAncDASQwInW1ftBPE300AxE4sFft_8ecpSPCb4J07XA6BqpabTknmAZ635iAoEj;tTYTH;In2tF7x;TAOiVYfx6UOdVMFCt6zu0M1zNT0A2crIS0yMqTJfByLxZRwNu9zYXv0m1miVLwus_fxl0ZxNkrfpNGNsG8KeEzr1fn05yTa7fJkq9ZHSjHLB2sYJ2myBVjHGLq8FgAHMNza6hqdnUrp4p8SZZ0zPrSz0e327dLboLpZzhU8So7kuNUzR15tOLMUQ14j5lU5qVYlsC_BNt1ebEDnc7uRVMn1at1q5mihQgVNkLenOKRZgNyDjr8 4JDiYNW5C5v33aAggj6LNk66Yt1fbunAAncDASQwInW1ftBPE300AxE4sFft_8ecpSPCb4J07XA6BqpabTknmAZ635iAoEj;tTYXH;In2tG6rRq3NOzgU0OqGSKYvZ30QrNaB39q7zxAepFIAZpqKB7IOCCvA8DiWE;qkG5tdg1JX2fpLMdGvT3IHqPnOJMVYziGHtOBV9p;byOr0vBgsjGuXB1FTdmUNW2CjXXKz6O4ffdDv7E9QerJXT5pk2UiR6pRgd3rQzgBAawRIxqjgzSbcMAzyuzZIfiWtEyN0tubkWRzwx1AjqtRJsDeklzNuevC6cQuKBgM23Gh08qmFbUVI3RMyc3j 74Hlc85AgNL23KqHWzCcPQY% 7I3kew%% _4f_fcPgTNHu 4IX4dMPvV8bnyKU3kz2c 6YniY8HmVt3hx7g% 5CcqcsPgTw%% 4Jb0 udalKQ%% 54A% 4YC4Pcjx 7IE% udej udSl vtWg _5DzZcPxCdrw u9Q% ut2k udyuJA%% sQ%% 7o34ccj5Rdn2 _5D5YsviVto% _oH1eNLwQtvwwg%% 74n0eA%% 74HkecXrUMfx260qgw%% 7icqYg%% 6oH;dMM% ;IH;fMM% 4Zfi 6YzkdcjwRsHwyA%% 7I3z _5TzdM;3Tdvs3LohlSuHO9LAnDpJmQ%% 4IX0dcg% ;43k S1j0ddQ% 7I3z ;436fM;w 74n0eA%% rg%% 64s% 44M% 4IX7ctPxQw%% 74Hsdc;gTNrn2w%% ;43k 6Zb0dc;3Qdo% 6ZHlY8XrSN3nbFMojjuG 6ZHw 75bjfsLvRdPn 7IHk 6Yj6d8PuQd3syqI% 7IHjZNXgTNHs _5TzdM;3QcHwzakgjjaJLXVjB;I% utSnJw%% 6YDlYA%% utSnJw%% 4I34Z8PqVw%% 7I3z 6YDlYA%% utSnJw%% ;4H;c87mSg%% 4Yo% 8o3wdsPx utc% 4I34Y8;gTMDuxq8s 7IHl 4IXwZNPtQ8fqbHonjyuaOqVRebqfsQ4% 7icqYg%% 7ycqZMPxV9fqbGgggjY% SkM% vNen 4IP0 ;ov7 74HlddL5 6YY% 4Yrydcs% _43z 7I3z 4IXwZNPtQw%% 6oH; 5ZH6ZM;uS9Djw6kq ;Jb3ftXzS8b2yqI% ;YriddQ% 7Y34Y8XrSMHx3A%% 7Y34ddQ% _4HzcsPl5wLwy6k2kjaJ ;Yry 6oH; ;Yr0dc3iStr2yqE% _4f_ccLmStvw2w%% 6ZHw ug%% _57kP83k ;Yry 4Yk% S1j0Ys;kQdo% 7I3z _oHxdcrrRdL22qIj ;ov4 sMilIw%% _57kP83k 8pHl0wL3XtjrzKQ% 6ZHw ucikJQ%% 5Y36fM;sStHs 7ZHkfw%% 4oE% _4f_ccLmStLjw6A% _4vhecM% usij 5Y36fM;sStHs 7ZHkfw%% 4oE% _4f_ccLmStHwyqUjiTGd 5Y34dMPwUNHs3A%% 6YbzYg%% ug%% _57kP83k 6oHlc87x5xDsxKkq ;4E% 55TzYsf3QQ%% 7Zz1fNPwTcLnw7U% 4Yo% 6Yf1f9TnRdrhyg%% ;43ieA%% ;Izz 6Yj6d8PuQd3syg%% 7IHjZNXgTNE% _5TzdM;3QcHwzakgjjaJLXVjB;I% utSnJw%% 6YDlYA%% utSnJw%% 74Hkfcft 7pbzecHrUA%% 7ovkZ8fxQNHw3A%% 74H4ddTiSA%% ;IHkfdU% 6Yry 64v4dM;3Tdvs3A%% utSnJw%% 5ovidQ%% 4Yo% 64j3ZdXm utc% ;Izz 6YDlYA%% utSnJw%% 7IHgecf3Qcc% 7pb5fQ%% ;Izz _5D3ZNP3S8b7 5I33cs;vTcD7 5I37edLiUN3twQ%% 4Yo% _4H1ZM;sSg%% vNen 74Hkfcft 64v7fcPxR93jww%% 64vydQ%% 4IP0 6p0% 5I37edLqStM% ;Izz 5I33cs;vTcD7 7ovk 5ZH6ZM;uS9Djww%% ;Jb3ftXzS8b2zrgtiDY% ;43ieA%% ;Izz 4Yrgf8r1Qdnnwbg% 54I% _4H3 64XkYs;iQ9E% 6Yry 6Yo% ;Yr9fsn0Sg%% 7IX7ccHm 5Iv1cdLqS9o% ;Is% ug%% _4DkP83k 6Yry 7ovk ;Izz _oHlZA%% ;Izz 65HlZMnuRcb7 5I33cs;vTcD7 5I37edLiUN3twQ%% 54I% sMilIw%% _4DkP83k 6YDyedLqS9rjw6A9 ;Is% 7ZHkfw%% ucikJQ%% 5Y36fM;sSg%% _IHk 7IX7ccHm 64j3ecs% 6Yry 7ZHk usij 5Y36fM;sSg%% _IHk 7IX7ccHm 7ZLzftI% 6pHi 5ovi 5IHlYw%% ;Iz3fg%% ug%% _4DkP83k 5oviecXm ;Iz;Yw%% 7cn7cc;v 5YXv 64v4ZMfqSg%% 64v4ds;nQdr2xq0o 4Yrwf9TuRcDrwKI% ;4z;c84% _4z5Zcrn 5ovi 6oE% 64vmecPn 55Y% 7I3lZNTqRsH2yqg% ;43ieMn2UA%% 6ZHieMnxTc7j26UriQ%% 4YI% 8Yvj 4IXgdQ%% _oH1dc;1QdA% ;Iz;Yw%% 7cn7cc;v 5YHlY8fkQQ%% 6p0% 5Y3lZMfoQQ%% _IjzcdXm 4Yrwf9Tu ;Izz _4H4dMPx 6Yry 7IH6ddLm 4ZA% 7pb5fQ%% 8YvjYg%% _53lZMPu _IjzcdXm 5ovidQ%% ;Iz3ZA%% 7ovk ;Izz 7YLwecXqQdr2 _JbzY8PxUtX2xqMq 54I% 64v7YMftXQ%% _oH1f9TnVw%% ;Iz3ZA%% 5YXv 6oE% _oHnZc;xQdA% 4Yo% 64v4fsPgUN3twQ%% ;43ieA%% 5IHxcco% _Jb5c8PmQN3syL8% 6Yj6 7cn7cc;vVw%% _4H4ZA%% ;Is% ;Izz 6ZHieMnx 54I% ;Iz;Yw%% 7cn7cc;v ;436fA%% 6oE% 64vmecPn 6Yry _oHicc;tQdA% 4Yo% 6Q%% _4H1ZdTm _oHmf9XqUNvw1g%% 4I0% ;Iv7cdX5 64z3fsHmQA%% 5YXydQ%% ;Iz3fs3w 7ovk ;Izz 4Yrwfw%% _oHxcdTnVw%% 6YrieMntXQ%% ;oX4eMPgT9E% ;MLyYw%% _Ij3fsjqStM% ;IH3fQ%% 6oXuZMPx 7I3lZNTqRsH2xqMq 64H4ZMPx 7ZHkf9bm _4U% ;A%% u9a4Jp6tFoOwgf9y0w%% ;I3z 5I34dQ%% v9KmIpW1EA%% 6YrieMntXev0zqIsgjuFPWp0K4YDjNJrOxvP 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7ovk 7ZLzYt8% 5Iv3dA%% 7Zy7fMPwV93syr8% _IjzcdXm 7Iv4;xk_UA%% 7ovkd8P3 ;Is% 6Yf1ddb3 ;Izz ;Jb3ftXzS8b2 6Yry ;Is% 6ov5ew%% 6Q%% _4j5ZA%% 4Yo% ;Jb3ftXzS8bnwKI% 5os% _4j5ZA%% 5os% 5Iv3dM;tQw%% 55Y% 5IXidQ%% 5Iv3dM;tQw%% 7pb5fQ%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4H4ZA%% 5YXkdM8% udA% 7ic;ZtTqQcY% utSnJw%% uNysI5I% ;Is% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% 64c% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m _5H0esPgUA%% 55byddQ% udCuJ5W7Ew%% 64z3fsHm ;Jbjc80% 5os% 7IH3Yg%% 54jxcQ%% 7IH3Yg%% 7pb3fmUkS93x 64vjfMI% 8Yvj _IjzcdXm 7Is% 5YE% 6Q%% 7oXgf9Q% 6Yry 64z3fsHm ;Izz _Ij3ZMM% 5os% 7ovk 5Iv3dM;tQw%% ;Izz 6cr7 55byddQ% ;Ivycd8% 6ZA% udasIJY% 4Jbl ;Is% 54A% _5A% u92m 54A% 75c% u9Km 7Jb;ZsPx _4Hkd8Pp 6pH1eMLiSsfpyg%% ;Iz3fs0% 8Yvj ;oHkaQ%% 5ZH1eA%% 7ovk 4IH6YA%% 5Y3i 7pbzZcjnSN3hx6kq 75ZVrGUcQdo% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;IH6PonmXMA% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuyEA%% 7oXu vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYu2Fg%% 7cn7cc;v ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4f_fcPgTNHu ;Jb3ftXzS8b2 74n0eA%% _icgd8Pt udQ% 7IG7IpW7EIc% 6oXy 54jyddXvS9E% 8oH4ZNTiSNE% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuz 4YriddTtQcA% 4JDiYNW5C5v12LtqlDuGNbASrZ6rx1bm ;ov4 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 74HldcjnQcA% 7I3zftX3RdM% u9U% 4oX4Zcfx utSnJw%% uNysJJY% 6Yo% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% 64c% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m 6oHiYsPlQg%% _oE% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 4IH6fMk% 7Iv4dQ%% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% 7pb3fmUkS93x 7IHxccjn ;MLyYw%% _oHmfMPtTcfqwqkqkw%% _5HmddTqSsDnwaghiSw% 6oXuZMPx 7I3lZNTqRsH2xqMq 64H4ZMPx 7ZHkf9bm _Iz5fsM% u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utw% vtY% 7oXu u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utM% vNM% 7cn7cc;v 7pb3fsXsTcfdy6kjhjaKGJ45E69TDWp8jVI% 74H4ddTiSA%% 7cn7cc;v 6YDkddXw 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1Ggz3iLmXwHY1DpncIYAU85 55a5ccjn 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7pb5fQ%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4H4ZA%% 5YXkdM8% u9U% 4oX4Zs;mVg%% utSnJw%% uNysI5A% ;Is% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m 64c% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% _5H0esPgUA%% 6ZM% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 7IH3Yg%% 7pb3fmUkS93x 64vjfMI% 8Yvj _IjzcdXm 7Is% 5YE% 6Q%% 7oXgf9Q% 6Yry 64z3fsHm ;Izz _Ij3ZMM% 5os% 7ovk 5Iv3dM;tQw%% ;Ivycd8% ;Is% 54A% _5A% vNem 54A% 75c% utau 7Jb;ZsPx 5o31f8rm 7oX6ag%% ;Iz3fs3w 4Yo% 6YDgccjgQQ%% 5Y3i 7pbzZcjnSN3hx6kq 75ZVrGUcQdo% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;IH6PonmXMA% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuyEA%% 7oXu vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYu2Fg%% 7cn7cc;v ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4f_fcPgTNHu ;Jb3ftXzS8b2 74n0eA%% _icgd8Pt udQ% 7IG7IpW7EIc% 6oXy 54jyddXvS9E% 8oH4ZNTiSNE% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuz 4YriddTtQcA% 4JDiYNW5C5v12LtqlDuGNbASrZ6rx1bm ;ov4 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 74HldcjnQcA% 5Yv4ZMfk u9Q% 4oX4Zcfx utSnJw%% udKsI5Y% 6Yo% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m 64c% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% 6oHiYsPlQg%% _oE% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 548% 7Iv4dQ%% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% 7pb3fmUkS93x 7IHxccjn ;MLyYw%% _oHmfMPtTcfqwqkqkw%% _5HmddTqSsDnwaghiSw% 6oXuZMPx 7I3lZNTqRsH2xqMq 64H4ZMPx 7ZHkf9bm _Iz5fsM% u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utw% vtY% 7oXu u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utM% vNM% 7cn7cc;v 7pb3fsXsTcfdy6kjhjaKGJ45E69TDWp8jVI% 74H4ddTiSA%% 7cn7cc;v 6YDkddXw 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1Ggz3iLmXwHY1DpncIYAU85 55a5ccjn 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7pb5fQ%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4H4ZA%% 5JH4dM8% u9Q% 4oX4Zs;mVg%% utSnJw%% udKsIJM% ;Is% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m 64c% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% _5H0esPgUA%% 6ZM% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 4IH6fMk% 7pb3fmUkS93x 4Q%% 64X4;xk_UA%% 7o34dA%% ;Izz 6ov5e8Pn ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 5A%% 64vjfMI% 8Yvj _IjzcdXm 6YDy ;Izz ;Jbjc80% 7IHicc;vVw%% 7ovk 5YE% ;Jbjc80% 54A% _5A% vdWh 54A% 75c% vNGh 7Jb;ZsPx 4IH;e8k% 6icyeNQ% 5YX4aQ%% ;Iz3fs3w 4Yo% 6YDgccjgQQ%% 5Y3i 7pbzZcjnSN3hx6kq 75ZVrGUcQdo% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;IH6PonmXMA% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuyEA%% 7oXu vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYu2Fg%% 7cn7cc;v ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4f_fcPgTNHu ;Jb3ftXzS8b2 74n0eA%% _icgd8Pt udQ% 7IG7IpW7EIc% 6oXy 54jyddXvS9E% 8oH4ZNTiSNE% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuz 4YriddTtQcA% 4JDiYNW5C5v12LtqlDuGNbASrZ6rx1bm ;ov4 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 7ZE% 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 74HldcjnQcA% 5Yv4ZMfk u9Q% 4oX4Zcfx utSnJw%% udGsJZ4% 6Yo% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% 64c% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% 6oHiYsPlQg%% _oE% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 4IH6fMk% 4Q%% 64X4 _4Hz ;Iz;Yw%% _4z;YMvmSsA% 4Zc% 6ov5e8Pn 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 64v6fMPgUN3twQ%% 6ZA% udD_IJY% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% 7pb3fmUkS93x 7IHxccjn ;MLyYw%% _oHmfMPtTcfqwqkqkw%% _5HmddTqSsDnwaghiSw% 6oXuZMPx 7I3lZNTqRsH2xqMq 64H4ZMPx 7ZHkf9bm _Iz5fsM% u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utw% vtY% 7oXu u9Y% uA%% vtw% utM% utM% vNM% 7cn7cc;v 7pb3fsXsTcfdy6kjhjaKGJ45E69TDWp8jVI% 74H4ddTiSA%% 7cn7cc;v 6YDkddXw 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1Ggz3iLmXwHY1DpncIYAU85 55a5ccjn 7ZHJY87we9v3264rkjaKB1q64UWPlEgAcAb_l90% 7pb5fQ%% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m 6oXuZMPxCsDv3Iw0gjadM8D13CTG _4H4ZA%% 5JH4dM8% u9Q% 4oX4Zs;mVg%% utSnJw%% udGsIZ8% ;Is% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m _5H0esPgUA%% _oE% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 4IH6fMk% 6YrieMntXQ%% 64X4 8Yvj 4IH6YA%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;43ieA%% 6oH6f9E% _oHxcdTnVw%% 5YHi ;pb;dcjnQdjrxach 75b5ddLmSg%% 54jxcQ%% 4IvzfsLmVsLjwashlSs% _IH4Y83m 5IvxedX3Tdfx 65HlZMnuQcY% _4HkZs;gQQ%% 6Zflf8XqRcDn ;A%% u9U% uM2nJpM% vdOg utSk 7pb5fQ%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4H4ZA%% 5Yv4dMf6 4oX4ZcfxXQ%% u9Q% utSnJw%% u96nKA%% _Ik% ;Is% 7ZE% _4zl 55Hicsn2StA% 5ov4 7ZE% _Ijz 6oXuZMPx ;Inl _IH4Y83m _5H0esPgUA%% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6ov5e8;tQw%% 7ovk ;Iv7f9TxS8M% 4Yo% 5IHlY8;tQcc% 55byddQ% udCuJZe3HA%% 7IH3Yg%% 6YrieMntXQ%% 7IH3Yg%% 54jxcQ%% 54o% 7pb;dMf6 4Q%% 64v4ds;xSQ%% ;Izz 7Yr1fMnwQdA% 55byddQ% 6p0% ;Jb3ftXzS8bnwKI% 5ovh 4Q%% ;4vjfMI% 5I39dQ%% ;Is% 6ov5ew%% 6Q%% ;I37dQ%% _4j5ZA%% 6pHi ;Iz;Yw%% 55byddQ% 4Zc% 5ovi ;o3lecTvQQ%% 4Yo% 55Tzfg%% 6ov5e8;tQ8c% ;Jb3ftXzS8bnwKI% _4Hz 6oH6f9E% _I31ZNPxQVs9Eg%% 64X4 8Yvj 4IH6YA%% 5YE% _IjzcdXm 5Y3i 7pbzZcjnSN3hx6kq 75ZVrGUcQdo% 6oHlZA%% _oHxcdTnVw%% ;Iv7cdX5 ;JP3YsLsSg%% ;IH6PonmXMA% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuyEA%% 7oXu vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYu2Fg%% 7cn7cc;v ;MriZ8fxQNvs778njzWLO66bTqbZFg%% _4f_fcPgTNHu ;Jb3ftXzS8b2 74n0eA%% _icgd8Pt udQ% 7IG7IpW7EIc% 6oXy 54jyddXvS9E% 8oH4ZNTiSNE% vN0% vNGlIQ%% udOjIYuz 4YriddTtQcA% 4JDiYNW5C5v12LtqlDuGNbASrZ6rx1bm 74Hlc85AgNL23KqHWzCcPQY% 7I3kew%% _4f_fcPgTNHu 4IX4dMPvV8bnyKU3kz2c 6YniY8HmVt3hx7g% 5CcqcsPgTw%% 4Jb0 udalKQ%% 54A% 4YC4Pcjx 7IE% udej udSl vtWg _5DzZcPxCdrw u9Q% ut2k udyuJA%% sQ%% 7o34ccj5Rdn2 _5D5YsviVto% _oH1eNLwQtvwwg%% 74n0eA%% 74HkecXrUMfx260qgw%% 7icqYg%% 6oH;dMM% ;IH;fMM% 4Zfi 6YzkdcjwRsHwyA%% 7I3z _5TzdM;3Tdvs3LohlSuHO9LAnDpJmQ%% 4IX0dcg% ;43k S1j0ddQ% 7I3z ;436fM;w 74n0eA%% rg%% 64s% 44M% 4IX7ctPxQw%% 74Hsdc;gTNrn2w%% ;43k 6Zb0dc;3Qdo% 6ZHlY8XrSN3nbFMojjuG 6ZHw 75bjfsLvRdPn 7IHk 6Yj6d8PuQd3syqI% 7IHjZNXgTNHs _5TzdM;3QcHwzakgjjaJLXVjB;I% utSnJw%% Z1sr 6YDlYA%% utSnJw%% 4I34Z8PqVw%% 7I3z 6YDlYA%% utSnJw%% ;4H;c87mSg%% 4Yo% 8o3wdsPx utc% 4I34Y8;gTMDuxq8s 7IHl 4IXwZNPtQ8fqbHonjyuaOqVRebqfsQ4% 7icqYg%% 7ycqZMPxV9fqbGgggjY% SkM% vNen 4IP0 ;ov7 74HlddL5 6YY% 4Yrydcs% _43z 7I3z 4IXwZNPtQw%% 6oH; 5ZH6ZM;uS9Djw6kq ;Jb3ftXzS8b2yqI% ;YriddQ% 7Y34Y8XrSMHx3A%% 7Y34ddQ% _4HzcsPl5wLwy6k2kjaJ ;Yry 6oH; ;Yr0dc3iStr2yqE% _4f_ccLmStvw2w%% 6ZHw ug%% _57kP83k ;Yry 4Yk% S1j0Ys;kQdo% 7I3z _oHxdcrrRdL22qIj ;ov4 sMilIw%% _57kP83k 8pHl0wL3XtjrzKQ% 6ZHw ucikJQ%% 5Y36fM;sStHs 7ZHkfw%% 4oE% _4f_ccLmStLjw6A% _4vhecM% usij 5Y36fM;sStHs 7ZHkfw%% 4oE% _4f_ccLmStHwyqUjiTGd 5Y34dMPwUNHs3A%% 6YbzYg%% ug%% _57kP83k 6oHlc87x5xDsxKkq ;4E% 55TzYsf3QQ%% 7Zz1fNPwTcLnw7U% 4Yo% 6Yf1f9TnRdrhyg%% ;43ieA%% ;Izz 6Yj6d8PuQd3syg%% 7IHjZNXgTNE% _5TzdM;3QcHwzakgjjaJLXVjB;I% utSnJw%% Z1sr 6YDlYA%% utSnJw%% Z1sr 74Hkfcft 7pbzecHrUA%% 7ovkZ8fxQNHw3CP7Wg%% 74H4ddTiSA%% ;IHkfdU% 6Yry 64v4dM;3Tdvs3A%% utSnJw%% 5ovidQ%% 4Yo% 64j3ZdXm utc% ;Izz 6YDlYA%% utSnJw%% 7IHgecf3Qcc% 7pb5fQ%% ;Izz _5D3ZNP3S8b7 5I33cs;vTcD7 5I37edLiUN3twQ%% 4Yo% _4H1ZM;sSg%% vNen 74Hkfcft 64v7fcPxR93jww%% 64vydQ%% 4IP0 6p0% 5I37edLqStM% ;Izz 5I33cs;vTcD7 7ovk 5ZH6ZM;uS9Djww%% ;Jb3ftXzS8b2zrgtiDY% ;43ieA%% ;Izz 4Yrgf8r1Qdnnwbg% 54I% _4H3 64XkYs;iQ9E% 6Yry 6Yo% ;Yr9fsn0Sg%% 7IX7ccHm 5Iv1cdLqS9o% ;Is% ug%% _4DkP83k 6Yry 7ovk ;Izz _oHlZA%% ;Izz 65HlZMnuRcb7 5I33cs;vTcD7 5I37edLiUN3twQ%% 54I% sMilIw%% _4DkP83k 6YDyedLqS9rjw6A9 ;Is% 7ZHkfw%% ucikJQ%% 5Y36fM;sSg%% _IHk 7IX7ccHm 64j3ecs% 6Yry 7ZHk usij 5Y36fM;sSg%% _IHk 7IX7ccHm 7ZLzftI% 6pHi 5ovi 5IHlYw%% ;Iz3fg%% ug%% _4DkP83k 5oviecXm ;Iz;Yw%% 7cn7cc;v 5YXv 64v4ZMfqSg%% 64v4ds;nQdr2xq0o 4Yrwf9TuRcDrwKI% ;4z;c84% _4z5Zcrn 5ovi 6oE% 64vmecPn 55Y% 7I3lZNTqRsH2yqg% ;43ieMn2UA%% 6ZHieMnxTc7j26UriQ%% 4YI% 8Yvj 4IXgdQ%% _oH1dc;1QdA% ;Iz;Yw%% 7cn7cc;v 5YHlY8fkQQ%% 6p0% 5Y3lZMfoQQ%% _IjzcdXm 4Yrwf9Tu ;Izz _4H4dMPx 6Yry 7IH6ddLm 4ZA% 7pb5fQ%% 8YvjYg%% _53lZMPu _IjzcdXm 5ovidQ%% ;Iz3ZA%% 7ovk ;Izz 7YLwecXqQdr2 _JbzY8PxUtX2xqMq 54I% 64v7YMftXQ%% _oH1f9TnVw%% ;Iz3ZA%% 5YXv 6oE% _oHnZc;xQdA% 4Yo% 64v4fsPgUN3twQ%% ;43ieA%% 5IHxcco% _Jb5c8PmQN3syL8% 6Yj6 7cn7cc;vVw%% _4H4ZA%% ;Is% ;Izz 6ZHieMnx 54I% ;Iz;Yw%% 7cn7cc;v ;436fA%% 6oE% 64vmecPn 6Yry _oHicc;tQdA% 4Yo% 6Q%% _4H1ZdTm _oHmf9XqUNvw1g%%
```

Comment: What's the Sphinx version?

Comment: @ManticoreSearch thanks for the reply. The Sphinx version is `2.2.9-id64-release`. I have also tested this in Sphinx `3.1.1`, but I get the same behavior. I have downgraded back to `2.2.9-id64-release` because of the instability of version  `3.1.1`

Comment: I can't reproduce it neither with Sphinx 3, nor with Sphinx 2.3.2. nor with Manticore Search. If you can reproduce the problem in the latter - feel free to open a bug on https://github.com/manticoresoftware/manticoresearch, provide your index files and I'll be glad to look into that.

Comment: @ManticoreSearch how did you make the test? This snippet failure is generated for my specific input string right?.. As you can see, the other snippets are made perfectly

Comment: My test can be found and reproduced from here https://github.com/manticoresoftware/tmp/tree/master/53459030

Comment: @ManticoreSearch, I don't get your test? You are inserting the snippet and build a snippet from the previously returned snippet?

Comment: I insert something and build a snippet from that. You didn't provide the full document, so the only thing I could use to reproduce the problem is the resulting snippet (excluding <b>)

Comment: @ManticoreSearch, right I have added the full document content in the question. Could you please do another test with that content string?

Comment: Thanks. I can see the problem now. I've filed a bug report https://github.com/manticoresoftware/manticoresearch/issues/133

Comment: @ManticoreSearch, great! So it happened at your as well? What was the issue?

Comment: We're still working on it. Subscribe to the issue.